# Can you change a dynamic link target without recompiling?

Tags: symlink, dynamic-linking

I downloaded [a program](http://www.state-machine.com/qm/index.php) that unfortunately doesn't come as a source distribution. When I go to run it, I get the error

> error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The program seems to have been linked against a specific version of libjpeg which my distro does not have. Creating a symlink named `/usr/lib32/libjpeg.so.62` to my actual `libjpeg.so` fixes the problem, but poking around in `/usr/lib32` just to make one program work seems stupid and over the top.

Is there any way (sans recompiling) to make the program dynamically link `libjpeg.so` instead of `libjpeg.so.62`?

FWIW, `file` info for the program is

```
ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary-edit the file (with `vim -b` for instance) and replace any occurrence of `/usr/lib32/libjpeg.so.62` with some path to your `libjpeg.so` that is exactly the same size like for instance `/usr/lib//////libjpeg.so`

```
/usr/lib32/libjpeg.so.62
/usr/lib//////libjpeg.so
```

Comment: Replacing the `.62` with null characters did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I daresay that meddling with /usr/lib32/ by creating symlinks is much safer than a binary edit. My 2 cents. Also whats wrong with softlinks again?

Comment: @Arpith Nothing's wrong with symlinks, but I see no point in making changes to my entire system just to support a single application that was questionably linked.

Comment: The app is probably linked correctly, libraries have versions [for a reason](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html). ABI compatibility is the main concern, see http://upstream-tracker.org/versions/libjpeg.html for example. Such a naming method is coarse, but effective, there are [alternatives](http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=33).

Comment: @mr.spuratic, different distributions have different numbering schemes. This kind of issue typically occurs with libjpeg and with openssl where for instance debian and redhat do it differently. Binary-editing is as safe  as adding symlinks.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas That's one reason I use Slackware ;-) I'd go for a stub `libjpeg.so.62` that just did `dlopen("libjpeg.so.x.y",RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL)` on a newer library, set `LD_PRELOAD`, and cross my fingers...